# How to scale a MODIS image to get reflectivity in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, java, google-earth-engine

trying to scale the data, but error message ".multiply is not a function" keeps coming up.

I tried to multiply the first band "sur_refl_b01" by 0.0001 in order to get reflectivity from digital numbers.

here is my code, the last line is the one that gives me the error

```
var MODIS_scene = ee.Geometry.Point([41.17039409472716, 32.151341331337996]);
Map.centerObject(MODIS_scene,12);
var SR = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD09A1')
      .filterDate('2000-06-09');
print(SR)
Map.addLayer(SR, {bands: ['sur_refl_b01', 'sur_refl_b04', 'sur_refl_b03'], gamma: 1,       max:5108.8893684339855, min: -301.6111938308104, opacity: 1 } );

var GreenBands  = SR.select('Sur_refl_b01.').multiply(0.0001);
```